# confusion about when embedded object's copy constructor gets called

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor, composition

```
class WithCC { 
public:
  WithCC() {}
  WithCC(const WithCC&) {
    cout << "in WithCC's copy constructor" << endl;
  }
};


class Composite {
  WithCC withcc; // Embedded objects
public:
  Composite() {}
};

int main() {
  Composite c;
  Composite c2 = c;
}
```

With the code above, withcc's copy constructor gets called and I get the output:
*in WithCC's copy constructor*

But if I add a copy constructor to Composite like this...

```
class Composite {
  WithCC withcc; // Embedded objects
public:
  Composite() {}
  Composite(const Composite&) {
      cout << "in composite's copy constructor" << endl;
  }
};
```

withcc's copy constructor doesn't seem to get called because the output is:
*in composite's copy constructor*

Why isn't withcc's copy constructor called here?

Comment: Are you sure you included all the necessary code?  I would think the main problem is that `cout` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy constructor implicitly defined by the compiler performs a memberwise copy/move of its bases and members.

A user-defined copy-constructor defaault initializes subobjects of the derived class if their constructors were not called explicitly in the ctor-list.

So in your last code snippet you defined explicitly the copy constructor

```
  Composite(const Composite&) {
      cout << "in composite's copy constructor" << endl;
  }
```

but its ctor list is empty. So data member withcc will be default initialized.

I described this more detailed in my article

[Implicitly defined copy constructor and explicitly defined copy constructor: what is the difference?](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-1-0-00000021-000-0-0-1388485669)

Though it is written in Russian but you will be able to read it using for example google service translare.

Answer (score 3):

In the first sample you omitted a copy constructor for `Composite` and hence C++ generated a default one for you.  This default one essentially runs a field by field copy and hence was running the copy constructor of `WithCC`.

When you explicitly defined a copy constructor C++ does no magic.  It is up to you to copy the fields as necessary.  For example

```
Composite(const Composite& other) : withcc(other.withcc) {
      cout << "in composite's copy constructor" << endl;
}
```